# How to use star pattern with unapplySeq in Scala?

Tags: scala

I implemented simple `unapplySeq` that extracts elements of filepath to sequence:

```
object PathSequence {
  def unapplySeq(path: Path): Seq[String] =
    if (path == null || path.getFileName == null) Seq.empty
    else path.getFileName.toString +: unapplySeq(path.getParent)
}
```

After runing it like this:

```
val path = Path.of("C:/Users/WIN10/IdeaProjects/LearningSandbox/src/worksheet/resources/AddTwoNumbers.java")
val PathSequence(first, second, third, _*) = path
```

I get an error: `Star pattern must correspond with varargs or unapplySeq`.

`unapplySeq` is implemented correctly here, the result is `List(AddTwoNumbers.java, resources, worksheet, src, LearningSandbox, IdeaProjects, WIN10, Users)`

How to set first, second and third variables to first three elements of result sequence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently the problem is that `unapplySeq` also has to return an **Option[Seq[A]]**.

However, if you are sure that you will always match you can return a **Some[Seq[A]]**.
Check this:

```
object PathSequence {
  @annotation.tailrec
  private def loop(remaining: Option[Path], acc: List[String]): List[String] =
    remaining match {
      case Some(path) =>
        Option(path.getFileName) match {
          case Some(file) =>
            loop(remaining = Option(path.getParent), file.toString :: acc)
          
          case None =>
            List.empty
        }
      
      case None =>
        acc.reverse
    }
  
  def unapplySeq(path: Path): Some[List[String]] =
    Some(loop(remaining = Option(path), acc = List.empty))
}
```

Which you can see how it working [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/hWNr1Y0GQJGitJLsR1OmcA/32).